# setting up cocos2dx

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Ive installed cocos2d-x I can open up the sample in msvc 2010 and 2008 but can only add a new cocos2d-x project in msvc 2008.  I ran the install-templates-msvc bat file but it only installed the templates for 2008.

Does anyone know how i can fix this.  I am running all this on windows 7

Thanking You

Answer (score 1):

Edit install-templates-msvc.bat with a text editor , and add "pause" to the end of the file to see what happened.Chances are that your VS 2010 is not found by the script , and you can edit the template/msvc/installWizardForVS2010.js file to change its default diretory.